# SC189Z buck converter startup problems

Tags: buck, stability

I have a GPSDO design I've been building and selling for a while now, and it's mostly successful, but sometimes the 3.3v buck converter to power the oscillator won't start up properly.

It isn't universal - most of them work, but it happens often enough that I think there must be some aspect of the datasheet that I am not heeding 100% that's causing the design to not be 100% stable.

When it doesn't work, the output is more like 1.7 volts instead of 3.3 volts. Momentarily shorting out the 10 µF cap on the input of the SC189Z is enough to get it to start up properly (but obviously that's a pretty heinous workaround).

The schematic is [on the hackaday.io project page](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/6872294011648/GPS%20Disciplined%20VCxCXO%20v2_4_1.pdf). The 2.2 µH inductors are Murata 1285AS-H-2R2MP2s (I couldn't handily obtain the part mentioned in the datasheet). The 10µF, 0.1µF and 0.01µF caps are ordinary X7R 0805 ceramic caps. The input power is a 6W rated wall-wart style 5VDC power supply. The OH300 requires 3W at startup reducing down to 1.1W steady-state (at 3.3V).

The relevant portion of the circuit starts with the buck converter, which is followed by an additional 2.2µH inductor and 10µF cap and 0.1µF cap as a ripple filter. From there, there's about a 1 inch long 32 mil wide trace over to the OCXO, where there's another 10µF filter cap, a 400Ω ferrite bead and a 0.01µF cap, then the power supply pin for the oscillator.

Comment: WHere are your startup Vin, Vout waveforms?  It could be UVin or OVout

Comment: UVin and soft start look reasonably thought out, so it could be OVout. L3 and C29 form a 'lively' output filter, there is no dissipation, so perhaps it could overshoot? Scope the output and trigger on 3.3v+delta. If that is the case, you don't want to add series R, but a capacitively coupled shunt R, which will impact efficiency slightly, but you can control how much by the size of the C, should reduce overshoot. Otherwise, try driving EN after an input stabilisation period, cleaner than shorting Cin! Otherwise, post scope captures for good and bad startup.

Comment: As you do not appear to be holding the GPS chipset in reset at start, it is possible that (depending on component tolerances) the buck is going into current limit at start up (not an uncommon issue); shorting the input cap starts the output into a (slightly) pre-biased load which may allow it to start up when you do that.

Comment: The datasheet states that the *minimum* capacitance with a 2.2μH inductor is 10μF, so you are in fact at the minimums. As X7R devices exhibit not only DC bias effects but other things that reduce the effective capacitance, the loop *may* be unstable. See page 19 of the datasheet. (This is somewhat at odds of the corner frequency calculation on the same page).

Comment: @PeterSmith The GPS receiver is separately powered by an LDO. The buck converter at issue powers only the OCXO and nothing else. The GPS module *is* starting normally.

Comment: @Neil_UK The buck's feedback is taken before the 2nd ripple filter, so even if the final output overshoots the buck converter shouldn't actually see that... No?

Comment: @nsayer this is not going to be fixed by guesswork, scope traces??

Comment: @Neil_UK I will endeavor to capture some next chance I get (this evening - ~0200UTC).

Comment: It seems the mode that can get the SC189 to be stuck at 1.7V is over-current protection. There is a Soft-Start function that lasts 80us. There is a total 30uF of output cap. It would take an average net current of 30uF*3.3/80us = 1.24A to charge the 60uF cap to 3.3V within 80us. The Soft-Start average current is a fraction of the output current limit making it probably less than 1.24A. So the caps could be not fully charged when Soft-Start is over and the charging of the caps plus the high initial load of OCXO probably leads to the occasional over-current protection lock up.

Comment: A possible quick fix to try is to reduce C29 or C11. ... If a clean voltage to the OCXO is very important, I wonder if substituting the LC filter with a very low drop out regulator is a good alternative. The voltage wasted can be 0.5V or so.

Comment: In looking at the output on the scope during a failed power-up, the picture was unremarkable. The voltage rose to 1.7 volts within a few dozen microseconds and then began to ever so slightly sag. I haven't been able to reproduce it, but am letting that oscillator cool thoroughly for another attempt.

Comment: @rioraxe I will attempt to replace C29 and C11 with a 2.2µF cap and see if the supply voltage when it does work is acceptably smooth. If so, then you may be onto something with a combination of large capacitance and high startup load current. If so, then you should turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it. I'll try to confirm this evening if I can.

Comment: Reducing C29 and C11 to 2.2µF didn't have any impact on the ripple on the input of the oscillator (in fact, the measurement there is dominated by ~5 mV of blow-back from the oscillator itself). I've not been able to reproduce the failure, unfortunately, but I think I'll keep that change and see if it happens again.